# RSpec: How to mock an object and methods that take parameters

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, mocking

I'm writing RSpec unit tests for a `CommandLineInterface` class that I've created for my `Directory` object.  The `CommandLineInterface` class uses this `Directory` object to print out a list of people in my `Directory`.  `Directory` has a `#sort_by(param)` method that returns an array of strings.  The order of the strings depends on the `param` passed to the `#sort_by` method (e.g., `sort_by("gender")`.  What would be the correct way to mock out this `Directory` behavior in my CLI specs?  Would I use an instance_double?  I am not sure how to do this for a method that takes parameters, like sorting by gender.

I'm only using Ruby and RSpec.  No Rails, ActiveRecord, etc. being used here.

Snippets from the class and method I want to mock out:

```
class Directory
  def initialize(params)
    #
  end

  def sort_by(param)
    case param
    when "gender" then @people.sort_by(&:gender)
    when "name" then @people.sort_by(&:name)
    else raise ArgumentError
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Pasting actual code would make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how your objects are collaborating.

Some information is lacking in your question:

- How does `CommandLineInterface` use `Directory`? Does it create an instance by itself or does it receive one as an argument?
- Are you testing class methods or instance methods? (Prefer instance methods)

Here's how you could do it if you pass in the dependent object:

```
require 'rspec/autorun'

class A
  def initialize(b)
    @b = b
  end

  def foo(thing)
    @b.bar(thing)
  end
end

RSpec.describe A do
  describe '#foo' do
    context 'when given qux' do
      let(:b) { double('an instance of B') }
      let(:a) { A.new(b) }
      it 'calls b.bar with qux' do
        expect(b).to receive(:bar).with('qux')
        a.foo('qux')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If the class initializes the dependant object and it isn't important to know which instance got the message you can do this:

```
require 'rspec/autorun'

B = Class.new

class A
  def initialize
    @b = B.new
  end

  def foo(thing)
    @b.bar(thing)
  end
end

RSpec.describe A do
  describe '#foo' do
    context 'when given qux' do
      let(:a) { A.new }
      it 'calls b.bar with qux' do
        expect_any_instance_of(B).to receive(:bar).with('qux')
        a.foo('qux')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If you just want to stub out the return value and not test whether the exact message was received, you can use `allow`:

```
require 'rspec/autorun'

B = Class.new

class A
  def initialize
    @b = B.new
  end

  def foo(thing)
    thing + @b.bar(thing)
  end
end

RSpec.describe A do
  describe '#foo' do
    context 'when given qux' do
      let(:a) { A.new }
      it 'returns qux and b.bar' do
        allow_any_instance_of(B).to receive(:bar).with('qux') { 'jabber' }
        expect(a.foo('qux')).to eq('quxjabber')
      end
    end
  end
end
```